# Android Gyroscope - OpenGL LookAt Position

Tags: android, opengl-es, sensors, gyroscope

I want to get the exact position of the X, Y, Z position that I want to "**Look At**" through the ability of Gyroscope Sensor

I'm able to get to 9 value from Gyroscope Sensor, but I can't figure out the formula to get the exact position from this Gyroscope sensor.

I want the formula or an example to get the proper answer

Here is the code that I want the result to turn out

```
double standX = 0.0f, standY = 0.0f, standZ = 0.0f;
double lookX = 0.0f, lookY = 0.0f, lookZ = 1.0f;
double headupX = 0.0f, headupY = 1.0f, headupZ = 0.0f;
float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);

// code here

// in my onDraw
// I'm trying to make the lookAt position proper
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 
        eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, headupX , headupY, headupZ);
```

example of the result is below here:

[image: example of x=0, y=0, z=-1]

[image: example of x=0, y=1, z=0]

[image: example of x=1, y=0, z=1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finished my question 
and this is my solution

first, I need to made this 3 matrix to get result of x, y, z position

```
private float[] mRotXMatrix = new float[] {
 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
private float[] mRotYMatrix = new float[] {
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
private float[] mRotZMatrix = new float[] { 
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
```

Then in onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) method I rotate all these 3 matrix together with my camera view like this

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotXMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotXMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotYMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotYMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotZMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotZMatrix, 0);
```

And to get the X, Y, Z of my camera view, just get it from these matrix

```
viewX = mRotXMatrix[2];
viewY = -mRotYMatrix[6]; // +/- up to your initial camera view
viewZ = mRotZMatrix[10];
```